# Oracle Update Query issue with Replace function

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

I have a bunch of queries (simple update queries but with Replace function) which i run from my Oracle database. I know they should update rows as i had done select before preparing the scripts.

They look something like below :

```
update Table_X set VALUE = REPLACE (VALUE,'X0011'   ,'ENG=X0011'    ) where ColumnID = '23073' and Desc = 'label';
update Table_X set VALUE = REPLACE (VALUE,'A0011'   ,'ENG=X0011'    ) where ColumnID = '23073' and Desc = 'label';
update Table_X set VALUE = REPLACE (VALUE,'X0022'   ,'ENG=X0022'    ) where ColumnID = '23074' and Desc = 'label';
update Table_X set VALUE = REPLACE (VALUE,'A0022'   ,'ENG=X0022'    ) where ColumnID = '23074' and Desc = 'label';
update Table_X set VALUE = REPLACE (VALUE,'X0033'   ,'ENG=X0033'    ) where ColumnID = '23075' and Desc = 'label';
update Table_X set VALUE = REPLACE (VALUE,'A0033'   ,'ENG=X0033'    ) where ColumnID = '23075' and Desc = 'label';
```

Data is something like this : Table_X :

```
ID   ColumnID   Value    Desc
________________________________
1    23073      A0011   label

2    23074      A0022   label

3    23075      A0033   label
```

I ran the scripts for two sets of data :

1. trying to Replace `A00xx` to `X00yy` -> This returns 0 rows updated. I expect updates here.
2. trying to Replace `A00yy` to `A00xx` -> This runs correctly. (When i ran the respective script by using  correct numbers in the below queries , they show 1 row updated for each , although i expect only one query line to be replacing it).

Has anybody seen the behavior or can provide any clue?

Thanks in advance
T

Comment: Your points 1 and 2 doesn't reflect what you did on your update queries. Can you add what would be your expected result?

Comment: Point 1 does not make sense. In code you replace 'X0011'  with 'ENG=X0011' but you write you expect a Replace of A00xx to X00yy. You should not expect updates, there is no X0011 in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving your data sample this is what will happen with your current statements:

```
--will result in 1 row updated with no change
update Table_X set VALUE = REPLACE (VALUE,'X0011'   ,'ENG=X0011'    ) where ColumnID = '23073' and Desc = 'label';

-- will result in 1 row updated with value field as ENG=X0011
update Table_X set VALUE = REPLACE (VALUE,'A0011'   ,'ENG=X0011'    ) where ColumnID = '23073' and Desc = 'label';

-- will result in 1 row updated with no change
update Table_X set VALUE = REPLACE (VALUE,'X0022'   ,'ENG=X0022'    ) where ColumnID = '23074' and Desc = 'label';

--will result in 1 row updated with value field as ENG=X0022
update Table_X set VALUE = REPLACE (VALUE,'A0022'   ,'ENG=X0022'    ) where ColumnID = '23074' and Desc = 'label';

-- will result in 1 row updated with no change
update Table_X set VALUE = REPLACE (VALUE,'X0033'   ,'ENG=X0033'    ) where ColumnID = '23075' and Desc = 'label';

-- will result in 1 row updated with no change value field as ENG=X0033 
update Table_X set VALUE = REPLACE (VALUE,'A0033'   ,'ENG=X0033'    ) where ColumnID = '23075' and Desc = 'label';
```

`REPLACE` command will look for the second parameter on your field and if find it will replace by the third parameter.

Since you are filtering on your where clause all given rows will be updated but not all changed since the replace command will not find given string on that field.

Here: `VALUE = REPLACE (VALUE,'X0011','ENG=X0011')` you are saying: if the field value has this string `X0011` replace it by `ENG=X0011` since for that filtered row there isn't it will do nothing.

If you want to make this command to no rows updated:

```
update Table_X set VALUE = REPLACE (VALUE,'X0011'   ,'ENG=X0011'    ) where ColumnID = '23073' and Desc = 'label';
```

You have to add that string on the `where` filters like

```
update Table_X 
   set VALUE = REPLACE (VALUE,'X0011'   ,'ENG=X0011'    ) 
 where ColumnID = '23073' 
   and Desc = 'label' 
   and value = 'X0011';
```

Comment: Hello Jorge - I understand your suggestion about making no rows updated which answers my Point#2. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help @TiyasaTalukdar if you consider the answer helpful and it solve your problem please consider in accepting it. (click on the V on the left in the answer) !

Comment: For my point 1.. The reason i have a replace 'X0011' to'ENG=X0011' is because I made a mistake of not appending the ENG to some. Sorry I should have mentioned this at first.  The current scripts are to correct any such values. Now while i don't expect X0011 to be present in my table but A0011, I am still getting No rows updated. Do you see any reason for that? I tested this sample and it seems that the only time the query can fail is when the ColumnID does not match, otherwise it should always show x rows updated (even for no change). Am I correct?

Comment: Finally Thank you for your time in answering my question.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that your columnId is number type and you are using single quotes on it (in where filters). You shouldn't! This implies on implicit conversion and it may be messing up the results.

Comment: Another thing you can try is to use TRIM (as `trim(desc)`) on your filter for the Desc field because you are equaling it directly be if the field has `label ` (note the blank space) it will avail to no rows. Same for columnId if it is varchar.

Comment: Umm.. Well in realtime my ColumnID is Varchar, so that part is ruled out also no blank spaces , i verfied. But thank you for thinking out these pointers. I will do a select query and check again.

Comment: Glad to help. If you have any more doubts just ask.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like:

```
update table_x set value = case when value not like 'ENG=' then 'ENG=X'||substr(value, 2, length(value)) else value end;
```